# Get real order id inside transitional emails

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community

I need to customize some parts on the most "important" templates, like new order, status update etc, and I wanna put a link that takes the buyer directly to the order view page, which structure is:

http://mystore.com/sales/order/view/order_id/13/

So, my doubt is about how to get the real order id that ends the url, and the point is: when we use the variable {{var order.increment_id}}, system gets something like 100000013, and I need only "13", as we can see at the url above.

Is it possible to get only the real order id, without that "1000000..." ?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand here is that the increment id will not always match the entity ID (with a prefix), so don't try to strip the prefix off, you'll end in all kinds of mess.

It's been awhile since I've looked at this stuff, but I believe order in this case is an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`, so you should just be able to use `{{var order.getId() }}`. This should return the `entity_id` field from the database as opposed to the `increment_id`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I've seen this in a lot of big ecommerces in Brazil, they put in every email message a button such as "Click here to print your invoice" or "Click to pay now" and for those actions we need the order id, as expected. Is there some page in Magento docs where I can take for reference all available variables to use in email templates?

Comment: I'm not aware of a page, but you should be able to use almost any function on `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

Comment: Great, I will take a look at the model to see all options.

Comment: Your tip worked! I could get the order id using {{var order.getId() }}. Do you guess all variables from Mage_Sales_Model_Order could be used into the new order email template?